# AssertJ Core, is it possible to get error message with actual field/property difference when checking iterables/arrays content?

Tags: java, assertj

In Assertj Core you can compare ojects field by field recursively.

In this test **address.countryCode** differ in the two objects:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeEqual() {
    Person person1 = createPerson();
    Person person2 = createPerson2();
    assertThat(person1)
            .usingRecursiveComparison()
            .isEqualTo(person2);
}
```

I get error gessage:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual:
  Person@4b44655e
to be equal to: 
  Person@290d210d
when recursively comparing field by field, but found the following difference:

field/property 'address.countryCode' differ:
- actual value  : "US"
- expected value: "CA"

The recursive comparison was performed with this configuration:
- no overridden equals methods were used in the comparison (except for java types)
- these types were compared with the following comparators:
  - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
  - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
  - java.nio.file.Path -> lexicographic comparator (Path natural order)
- actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

When you get the actual field difference in the error message like above it is very helpful, but if I have a list and want to verify the content of the list:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeEqual2() {
    List<Person> personList = List.of(createPerson(), createPerson2());

    assertThat(personList)
            .hasSize(2)
            .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()
            .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(createPerson(), createPerson());
}
```

I get error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual:
  [Person@4fe767f3, Person@18ce0030]
to contain exactly in any order:
  [Person@2805c96b, Person@4445629]
elements not found:
  [Person@4445629]
and elements not expected:
  [Person@18ce0030]
when comparing values using recursive field/property by field/property comparator on all fields/properties using the following configuration:
- no overridden equals methods were used in the comparison (except for java types)
- these types were compared with the following comparators:
  - java.lang.Double -> DoubleComparator[precision=1.0E-15]
  - java.lang.Float -> FloatComparator[precision=1.0E-6]
  - java.nio.file.Path -> lexicographic comparator (Path natural order)
- actual and expected objects and their fields were compared field by field recursively even if they were not of the same type, this allows for example to compare a Person to a PersonDto (call strictTypeChecking(true) to change that behavior).
```

Is it not possible to get the actual field difference here like in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment because the error message built for `containsExactlyInAnyOrder` is not aware of the root cause of the assertion failure, in our case it does not know the comparison differences, it only knows that the assertion failed and build a generic error message.

We already have thought of supporting this use case but it is not straightforward to implement with the current way errors are designed.